# Location/city value is undefined after passing through other component and then render page gone blank..any solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-props, openweathermap

**I have two components "search" and "Maindata". I am passing the input value from the search component to maindata component where I want to replace the city attribute with the input value(location) in API. but the browser display went blank and the console give an undefined 'city' error, etc. I got stuck in this problem if anyone has a solution?**

**Here "search" component;**

```
import React , {useState} from "react";
import Maindata from "./Maindata";
import "../Componentstyle/search.css";
export default function Search() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState();
  <Maindata city={location}/>
  
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <nav className="istclass">
        <form className="form">
          <div className="search">
            <input
              value={location}
              placeholder="search city"
              className="searchbox"
              onChange={(e)=>setLocation(e.target.value)}
            />
            
            <button className="nd" onClick={(e)=>setLocation(e.target.value)}>
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Here "Maindata" component;**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../Componentstyle/Main.css";
export default function Maindata(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  
let city = console.log(props.city);
  let weather = async () => {
    const key = "1ab6ef20384db1d7d9d205d609f7eef0";
    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}&units=metric&formatted=0`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((actualData) => setData(actualData));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    weather();
  }, []);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const link = `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;

  return (
    <div className="maindata">
      <div className="city">{data.name}</div>
      <div className="temp">{data.main.temp} C</div>
      <div className="icon">
        <img src={link} alt="not found" />{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="feel">feels Like {data.main.feels_like} C</div>
      <div className="wind">Wind {data.wind.speed} Km/hr</div>
      <div className="cloudy">{data.weather[0].main}</div>
      <div className="humidity">humidity {data.main.humidity}%</div>
      <div className="sunrise">
        sunrise :- {new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toUTCString()}{" "}
      </div>
      <div className="sunset">
        sunset :- {new Date(data.sys.sunset * 1000).toUTCString()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Maindata city={location}/>
```

keep this line of code inside the return

Comment: then it will render twice the maindata components and still it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: give a default value to the city in useState

Comment: default value render in input which is fine but the page doesnot show the default result city as well

Comment: what's the error you got after giving the default city?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @ramkishore same thing is said in another answer you should elaborate a bit more

Comment: This is the error --> let city = console.log(props.city);  @AhsanKhalid  please remove console.log. It should be let city = props.city;

Comment: problem is that the input value from search component and weather function in maindata component has no link with each other..i think it should be done with statelifting but no idea how it will happen..if u have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no meaningful connection between the `Search` and `Maindata` components. Meaning `Maindata` component will not get rendered on the page because it is not in the `return` statement of the `Search` component.

The `Maindata` component as below, is in [JSX format](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), when you use JSX in your code in React, under the hood, [`React.createElement()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) method is being called.

Each call to React.createElement returns an object describing what to render to that part of the page. So it makes sense to put the `Maindata` component in the `return` statement. That is responsible for rendering the HTML elements from that component when you're loading a page containing that component.

```
<Maindata city={location}/> // is JSX and should be in the return statement to get rendered on the page and showing the right location
```

Comment: if I put Maindata component in the return statement it will render twice and still it's not solving my problem.

Comment: In your `Maindata` component change `let city = props.location` and in your Search component give `location` in state a default value (e.g. Paris). Also, the return statement in `Search` should have `Maindata`.